# Making HTTP Requests in RSpec outside of Controller Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have some feature tests where I want to mimic a malicous user that POSTs directly to a submit endpoint instead of using the form to submit a request.

In my controller tests I would have access to the `post` and `get` methods, but they are not available outside of Controller tests, it seems.

Is there any way I can access these in other types of tests so I can make web requests to my own app. I also need a way to bypass the `WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError` error that forbids any request from ever being made.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to move this outside of a controller test? Because this kind of sounds like a controller test.

Comment: I have a form where I have client-side JavaScript form validations enabled. I want to write tests that mimic a malicious user who might be trying to POST directly to same endpoint as the submit button or click the button with JS disabled on their browser, and check that my app handles that. The auth flow spans several controllers, so I guess that could be an integration test.  The clicking of the button is more of a feature/Capybar thing. Regardless of approach, I'd still be curious if this is possible for the sake of the question. Thanks!

Comment: Like you said, in this case the user is using a direct call / tool to post some malicious data to the controller. I think you should check this in a controller test. You probably could make `post` work in a feature test as well, but you probably need to include/require some libraries.. I can't help you with which to include. I can only point out that this still sounds like a controller test to me.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails use type: :request

```
RSpec.describe "MyIntegrationTest", type: :request do
  it 'gets by using the router' do
    get '/home'
  end
end
```